# Why doesn't the following code return A, AEC, AEBCD?

Tags: java, search, depth-first-search

I have a Depth Limited Search algorithm that I run several times in a loop so that the algorithm can act like an Iterative Deepening Search algorithm, 
Why does the code return the desired result only when I call the method explicitly but not when I call it in the loop.

```
public class DepthLimited {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Graph graph = new Graph();
    graph.addNode('A');    // Since A is the first vertex so it takes the index 0  
    graph.addNode('E');    // B is the second one so it takes index 1
    graph.addNode('B');    // index 2
    graph.addNode('C');    // index 3
    graph.addNode('D');    // index 4

    graph.addEdge(0, 1);     // This indicates the relation between the vertices A and E
    graph.addEdge(1, 2);     // This indicates the relation between the vertices E and B
    graph.addEdge(0, 3);     // This indicates the relation between the vertices A and C
    graph.addEdge(3, 4);     // This indicates the relation between the vertices C and D

 //        System.out.print("Sequence: ");
 //        graph.dls(2);
 //        System.out.println("");

    graph.dls(2); // produces AEBCD when called like this, before any other similar calls i.e graph.dls(1)

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        graph.dls(i);  // when i is 2 the method only returns A instead of AEBCD
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

And here's my Graph class:

```
public class Graph {

private final int MAX_NODES = 20;      //maximum number of nodes
private Node[] listOfNodes;        // list of nodes
private int neighbourMatrix[][];      // every node with its children
private int noOfNodes;              // current number of nodes
private Stack stack;

private int depth = 0;


public Graph() {
    listOfNodes = new Node[MAX_NODES];
    neighbourMatrix = new int[MAX_NODES][MAX_NODES];
    stack = new Stack();
}

public void addNode(char name) {
    listOfNodes[noOfNodes++] = new Node(name);        //create a new node and add it to the array of nodes
}

public void addEdge(int start, int end) {                //creates a bidirectional relation between
    neighbourMatrix[start][end] = 1;                     //the two nodes (start and end)
    neighbourMatrix[end][start] = 1;                     // 1 is used to indicate the existence of a relation between
}                                                        //two node because by default neighbourMatrix contains only 0s.

public void display(int node) {
    System.out.print(listOfNodes[node].name);          //prints the name of a node
}

public void dls(int limit) {                                 // begin at node 0 which is the root of the tree

    listOfNodes[0].checked = true;  // mark it
    display(0);                 // display it
    stack.push(0);                 // push it to the stack
    depth++;

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) // until stack empty,
    {
        int node = getUnvisitedChild(stack.peek());
        if (depth <= limit) {
            // get an unvisited child of the node that is at the top of the stack

            if (node == -1) // if the node had no unvisited child, then pop the node from the stack
            {
                stack.pop();
                depth--;
            } else // if the node has unvisited child         
            {
                listOfNodes[node].checked = true;  // mark it
                display(node);                 // display it
                stack.push(node);                 // push it to the stack
                depth++;
            }
        } else {
            stack.pop();
            depth--;
        }
    }
}

public int getUnvisitedChild(int v) // returns an unvisited child of the node v 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < noOfNodes; j++) {
        if (neighbourMatrix[v][j] == 1 && listOfNodes[j].checked == false) {
            return j;               //returns the index of the child
        }
    }
    return -1;              //otherwise it returns -1
}
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Comment: If `dls()` is supposed to be iterative, and it prints the vertices *as they are searched*, why would/should it print anything at all, if you *continue* a search that has already been completed? Seems you need to rethink your logic and/or your expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is two fold.

First, the `checked` value of each visited `Node` is set to `true` after `dls(int limit)` is called, and will remain so in subsequent calls to the method. You first need to set them to set `checked` back to `false`.

Second, `depth` is a class member variable/field and isn't reset to `0` each time. This variable should be local to the method.

I'd advise that you do not store whether they are visited as a property of the `Node`, but rather introduce a local `Set` (e.g. `HashSet`) that stores visited nodes; or in your case the integer values representing the index of the visited `Node` Objects.

For example, quickly hacking at your solution:

```
public void dls(int limit) {
    Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();
    int start = 0;
    stack.push(start);
    display(start);
    int depth = 1;
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        int current = stack.peek();
        visited.add(current);
        int next = -1;
        for (int adj = 0; adj < noOfNodes; adj++) {
            if (neighbourMatrix[current][adj] == 1 && !visited.contains(adj)) {
                next = adj;
            }
        }
        if (depth <= limit) {
            if (next == -1) {
                stack.pop();
                depth--;
            } else {
                stack.push(next);
                display(next);
                depth++;
            }
        } else {
            stack.pop();
            depth--;
        }
    }
}
```